# Cómo centrar horizontalmente una imágen y ponerla abajo del todo de un div

Tags: css, css3

Tengo una imágen dentro de un div, y lo que quiero hacer es mostrarla abajo del todo y centrada. Ahora se muestra seguida del contenido que tiene el div.
He conseguido hacer ambas cosas, pero de forma separada, es decir, cuando intento hacer las 2 cosas, no funciona.

```css
.story-box {
    background-color:#8bc34a;
    padding:0;
    height:300px;
    width:320px;
}
.swipe-up {
    height:70px;
    bottom:10px;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body story-box" id="story">
  <img class="swipe-up" src="//via.placeholder.com/100x70" />
</div>
```

Y esto es lo que quiero conseguir:

```
=============
|           |
|    DIV    |
|           |
|   [IMG]   |
=============
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una de tantas opciones para resolverlo es hacer que el contenedor se comporte como una celda de tabla y alinear verticalmente su contenido abajo (bottom), aunque esto no es del todo «natural» puesto que no estamos en un diseño que intente emular toda una tabla:

```css
.story-box {
    background-color:#8bc34a;
    padding:0;
    height:300px;
    width:320px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.swipe-up {
    height:70px;
    bottom:10px;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body story-box" id="story">
  <img class="swipe-up" src="//via.placeholder.com/100x70" />
</div>
```

**Mi solución favorita es con Flexbox**, haciendo que el contenedor sea de este tipo y asignando la alineación correspondiente al eje transversal (propiedad `align-items`), en este caso el vertical. Por último se puede manejar también la alineación horizontal con flexbox, con la propiedad `justify-content` en el contenedor:

```css
.story-box {
    background-color:#8bc34a;
    padding:0;
    height:300px;
    width:320px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.swipe-up {
    height:70px;
    bottom:10px;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body story-box" id="story">
  <img class="swipe-up" src="//via.placeholder.com/100x70" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo utilizar flexbox.

```css
.story-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  background-color:#8bc34a;
  padding:0;
  height:300px;
  width:320px;
}
.swipe-up {
  height:70px;
  width:100px;
}
.other-box{
  background-color:#50f00a;
  height: 70px;
  margin:2%;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body story-box" id="story">
  <div class="other-box">INFORMACION</div>
  <img class="swipe-up" src="//via.placeholder.com/100x70" />
</div>
```

Dentro del Código incluido lo importante son las 4 primeras líneas de la clase **.story-box**

En pocas palabras, defines al contenedor Padre como tipo **flex** y le indicas que todos sus hijos utilizaran una dirección tipo columna, y en esta forma para que el contenido aparezca en la parte de abajo utilizas **justify-content** (esto por ser columna), y para centrar el contenido usas **align-items**

Te recomiendo esta [guía de flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) muy bien explicada.

Comment: No es necesaria la línea de `flex-direction`, teniendo en cuenta que su valor por defecto es `row` y los valores de `justify-content` y `align-items` generan la misma solución.